# Is there any way to bind Dictionary<enum, bool> to Switch in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin, enums, binding

I have a Dictionary which comes from an API with **enumeration** as a **key** and **bool** as  a **value** e.g.:

```
Dictionary = new Dictionary<Permissions, bool>();
Dictionary.Add(Permissions.Create, true);
Dictionary.Add(Permissions.Delete, false);
...
```

I need to show a bunch of Switches on UI accordingly to permissions e.g.:

```
<Switch
  IsToggled="{Binding Dictionary[Create]}"/>
<Switch
  IsToggled="{Binding Dictionary[Delete]}"/>
```

But this doesn't work. It could work only if key was a string.

So is there any way to use Dictionary with enum key as a bindable property?

Comment: Have you tried using your dictionary as an itemsource for a listbox/listview with a custom item template, where the itemtemplate shows the enum/switch? I don't think you can do it any other way, other then creating a property for each permission.

Comment: This works. But this looks not the way I want to implement. I want to display the Switches inside cells of Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a intermediate variable. Here is the code for your reference.

Page1.xaml

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Create:Ture" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>
        <Switch x:Name="SWitch" VerticalOptions="Start"  IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled}"></Switch>
    </StackLayout>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{

    public static Dictionary<string, bool> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        keyValuePairs.Add("Create", true);
        SWitch.BindingContext = new SwitchModel(); 
    }
}
```

SwitchModel.cs

```
class SwitchModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    bool isToggle;
    public SwitchModel()
    {
        IsToggled = Page1.keyValuePairs["Create"];
    }
    public bool IsToggled
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref isToggle, value); }
        get { return isToggle; }
    }
    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

The result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyEQt.png)

Answer (score 0):

IsToggled binds with a bool value, then you must bind it with a bool property